# How do I increase the tick width of error bars in ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

I have a plot with y-error bars and would like to increase the tick size of my error bars.
This is the code for a simple example plot:

```
Data = Table[{X, Around[X, 0.5]}, {X, 1, 10}];
ListPlot[Data,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotMarkers -> {"+", 30}]
```

With this, the "+" that marks the point is much wider than the tick of the corresponding error bar and I want this to be the other way around.

I could only find a [solution for ErrorListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77865/how-do-i-adjust-error-bar-tick-size-with-errorlistplot), but none using the ListPlot and Around functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the options [`IntervalMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkers.html) and [`IntervalMarkersStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkersStyle.html) as follows:

```
ListPlot[Data, ImageSize -> Large, PlotMarkers -> {"+", 30}, 
 IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
 IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceWidth" -> .20, 
   "FenceStyle" -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
   "WhiskerStyle" -> 
       Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5], AbsoluteThickness[20],  Green]|>]
```

[image]

**Update:** To get plot markers aligned with the data coordinates we need to use graphics-based markers (see [this q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/125) about alignment issues with font-based markers).

Define

```
plus = Graphics @ First[First[
   ImportString[ExportString[Style["+", FontSize -> 24], "PDF"], 
     "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]]
```

and use it as

```
ListPlot[Data, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotMarkers -> {plus, 15}, 
 IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
 IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceWidth" -> .20, 
   "FenceStyle" -> Directive[Red, CapForm["Butt"], Thick], 
   "WhiskerStyle" -> 
     Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5], AbsoluteThickness[25], Green]|>]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this option!
The picture you posted is also a great example of an unrelated question I've had for a while: The distance from the lower end of the "+" to the lower error bar is significantly smaller than the distance from the upper end of the "+" to the upper error bar. Since the error is symmetric I would expect the distance to be the same, but I've seen similar things in Mathematica multiple times. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @camileri, thank you for the accept. I added a fix and a link re the marker alignment issue.

Comment: Wow, this exposes a much larger issue I've had: I have manually set PlotMarkers on many occasions and since
'PlotMakers -> {\[FilledCircle], 20}'
did not change the size of the plot marker, I often used
`PlotMakers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 20}` as this allowed me to change the size. I should obviously not have done this, because of the resulting alignment issue. Can you also tell me how I can properly change the size manually?
I cannot stress enough how helpful your comments were as it would have taken me forever to figure this out without your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: @camileri, you can use `PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[]}], .05}` instead of  `PlotMakers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 20}`.